# Nginx Fails To Start After Update To 1.25.4 - could not build optimal server_names_hash, then zero size shared memory zone "one"

Tags: nginx, ubuntu, memory, hash, start

I just updated nginx to 1.25.4 on one of my Ubuntu Linux 20.04.6 servers and it is now failing to start. Errors I am getting are as follows:

```
2024/03/07 12:46:28 [warn] 29836#29836: could not build optimal server_names_hash, you should increase either server_names_hash_max_size: 512 or server_names_hash_bucket_size: 64; ignoring server_names_hash_bucket_size
2024/03/07 12:46:28 [warn] 29836#29836: could not build optimal server_names_hash, you should increase either server_names_hash_max_size: 512 or server_names_hash_bucket_size: 64; ignoring server_names_hash_bucket_size
2024/03/07 12:46:28 [warn] 29836#29836: could not build optimal server_names_hash, you should increase either server_names_hash_max_size: 512 or server_names_hash_bucket_size: 64; ignoring server_names_hash_bucket_size
2024/03/07 12:46:28 [notice] 29836#29836: signal process started
2024/03/07 12:46:28 [error] 29836#29836: open() "/run/nginx.pid" failed (2: No such file or directory)
```

So I opened /etc/nginx/nginx.conf and modified the following in the `http` block:

```
server_names_hash_max_size 1024;
server_names_hash_bucket_size 128;
```

Then I try to start nginx again, but I get these errors:

```
2024/03/07 12:48:24 [notice] 30860#30860: signal process started
2024/03/07 12:48:24 [error] 30860#30860: open() "/run/nginx.pid" failed (2: No such file or directory)
```

I ran `systemctl status nginx.service` and it outputs the following:

```
● nginx.service - A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/nginx.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2024-03-07 12:49:55 UTC; 10s ago
       Docs: man:nginx(8)
    Process: 31367 ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/nginx -t -q -g daemon on; master_process on; (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Mar 07 12:49:55 Server-Name systemd[1]: Starting A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server...
Mar 07 12:49:55 Server-Name nginx[31367]: 2024/03/07 12:49:55 [emerg] 31367#31367: zero size shared memory zone "one"
Mar 07 12:49:55 Server-Name nginx[31367]: nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
Mar 07 12:49:55 Server-Name systemd[1]: nginx.service: Control process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Mar 07 12:49:55 Server-Name systemd[1]: nginx.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Mar 07 12:49:55 Server-Name systemd[1]: Failed to start A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server.
```

I also tried `journalctl -xe` for more details, but it does not seem to help me identify the issue. Here is the output.

```
A start job for unit nginx.service has begun execution.
-- 
-- The job identifier is 3603.
Mar 07 12:49:55 Server-Name nginx[31367]: 2024/03/07 12:49:55 [emerg] 31367#31367: zero size shared memory zone "one"
Mar 07 12:49:55 Server-Name nginx[31367]: nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
Mar 07 12:49:55 Server-Name systemd[1]: nginx.service: Control process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
-- Subject: Unit process exited
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- An ExecStartPre= process belonging to unit nginx.service has exited.
-- 
-- The process' exit code is 'exited' and its exit status is 1.
Mar 07 12:49:55 Server-Name systemd[1]: nginx.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
-- Subject: Unit failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- The unit nginx.service has entered the 'failed' state with result 'exit-code'.
Mar 07 12:49:55 Server-Name systemd[1]: Failed to start A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server.
-- Subject: A start job for unit nginx.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- A start job for unit nginx.service has finished with a failure.
```

The nginx server was working before I made the update to 1.25.4. Any idea what changed or what is causing this problem? I also tried purging nginx, reinstalling it and re-configuring it. Problem still persists. I do not have this problem on other servers.

UPDATE: I have deleted ALL virtual hosts and now nginx starts. Will try adding them one by one till it fails, so I discover what causes the error:

```
2024/03/07 12:46:28 [error] 29836#29836: open() "/run/nginx.pid" failed (2: No such file or directory)
```

Assuming the new version has some incompatibility of how nginx was set up. Oddly enough, it does not point me in a direction, i.e. a particular virtual host to be the problem. Will update again once I find out more.

Comment: There are three different errors reported at different times here, each of which would prevent nginx from starting. You fixed the first one. You didn't say if you took any action for the second one (open() "/run/nginx.pid" failed (2: No such file or directory)) which makes me wonder how you subsequently encountered a different error a few seconds later.

Comment: Weird, right? Just updated. Some of the many virtual hots may be the problem.

Comment: update the question please using `nginx -t`